# How to simplify an API without sacrificing Dependency Injection?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

Let's say I have a Rectangle class. To use it I'd do:

```
$rectangle = new Rectangle( 100, 50, new Color('#ff0000') );
```

However as this will be a public API, I want to simplify it for the end-users as much as possible. Preferably it will just accept the hex string:

```
$rectangle = new Rectangle( 100, 50, '#ff0000');
```

The problem now is that I need to instantiate the Color object inside the Rectangle class

```
class Rectangle {

    protected $width;
    protected $height;
    protected $fillColor;

    function __construct( $width, $height, $fillColor ){
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->fillColor = new Color( $fillColor );
    }
}
```

Having learned dependency injection this is considered bad. Or is it? What's the best approach?

Comment: How about using a factory, which will instantiate the Colour and pass it the constructor of Rectangle. Then the caller of the API will need to pass just the params.

Comment: Came here to say the same thing. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern

Answer (score 1):

I would use a factory class, which accepts an array (possibly) of arguments and returns the ready instantiated Rectangle object. There are many possibilities how to do that, depending on your design and your API specification.

```
class MyAPIFactory
{
    public function createRectangle($params)
    {
        // do some checks of the params
        $color = new Color($params['color']);
        Rectangle = new Rectangle($params['width'], $params['height'], $color);
        return $color;
    }
}
```

Further depending on your needs and design you can choose between `Factory Method` or `Abstract Factory`. Say you have an `interface GeometricalShape` and `class Rectangle implements GeometricalShape` as well as `class Circle implements GeometricalShape` for the first you could use something like

```
class MyApiFactory
{
    public static function createRectangle(array $params) { /*...*/ }
    public static function createCircle(array $params) { /*...*/ }
}
```

or

```
abstract class ShapeFactory
{
    /**
     * @return GeometricalShape
     */
    abstract public function createInstance(array $params);
    abstract protected function checkParams(array &$params);
}

class RectangleFactory extends ShapeFactory
{
    public function createInstance(array $params)
    {
        // ...    
    } 

    protected function checkParams(array &$params)
    {
        if(empty($params['width'])) {
            throw new Exception('Missing width');
        } 
        if (empty($params['height'])) {
            throw new Exception('Missing height');
        }
        // you could even make color optional
        if (empty($params['color'])) {
            $params['color'] = Color::DEFAULT_COLOR;
        }

    }
}
```